# Maven 2 reports 'java.util.List' cannot be instantiated error

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin

A user has reported that a maven plugin I maintain no longer works with maven 2 (it runs just fine under maven 3). It fails to parse the pom with the error

`Cause: Class 'java.util.List' cannot be instantiated`

A quick Google suggests that this is a bug in the maven model prior to 3.0 that has affected other plugins.

http://code.google.com/p/maven-samaxes-plugin/issues/detail?id=18

I recently added support for setting values via the command line by specifying expressions for List parameters, and it appears that this has triggered the bug.

```
 /**
 * @parameter expression="${targetClasses}" 
 */
  protected List<String>  targetClasses;
```

I can work around the problem by declaring the field as a concrete list type, but everyone knows that a fairy dies each time you do this.

Are there any nicer soloutions to this problem apart from withdrawing support for maven 2 or using concrete types?

Comment: What about the [annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html)?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the suggestion, but would the plugin still be compatible with maven 2 if I update to use annotations (isn't this a maven 3 feature)? If so is there a reason to believe that this would solve the original issue for maven 2 users?

Comment: Yes. Except with the running JVM which must be at least JVM 1.5. to be 100% sure you need to test with maven 2. I hope you aren't talking about Maven 2.0.X ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old now and you've answered your own question, I guess... Still, for completeness, here goes:

I'm using mvn 2.0.9 and had to migrate from `List<String>`:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${arguments}" 
 */
protected List<String> arguments;      //with or without generics, still complained!
```

to `String[]`:

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${arguments}" 
 */
protected String[] arguments;
```

The pom configuration is then as follows:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <arguments>
        <argument>arg1</argument>
        <argument>arg2</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Comment: where did you change this?

Comment: @FernandoGabrieli I don't have the code to hand any more. However, I had to change it in the class representing my maven plugin configuration - i.e. the class representing `arguments` above. I had to  revert it from `List<String>` to `String[]`.

Comment: thank you :) something that also work was to use a prev version of it